# Add Text to PayPal Redirect Page

Tags: paypal

I am looking to add some text to the standard PayPal re-direct page after a successful payment has been made....see the attached screenshot of the page I am trying to include text to....

Is this possible ?
Please advise where to configure
I have looked through all available settings in my PayPal account and cannot see it anywhere...

OK...I don't have enough points to post an image..
Here is a URL to the image
http://www.xlautomation.com.au/images/screen-capture-4.JPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web page you are referring to is the "PayPal Thank You" Page and no customization is possible on that page. The best way is to have your own return url specified and let the buyers redirected to your own thank you page after they redirected from PayPal thank you page .